# How to solve $n+1 \leq 2^{n-k}$ for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you solve $n+1 \leq 2^{n-k}$ for $n$?

This is my attempt (with $k=20$):
[image: This is my attempt]

Comment: When you do $2^{20}  = \frac{2^n}{n+1}$ and take logarithm, you get : $20 \log 2 = n\log 2 - \log (n+1)$. The $\log$ outside $n+1$ is missing, and then the whole question is wrong. This question can't be solved, you can only approximate the solution using IVT,

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I had to take the log of both sides. That alone doesn't really help me solve this, tho

Comment: As I tell  you : there is no way of removing a poly-logarithm from a question, you have to use IVT, except in trivial cases (and this is not a trivial case at all). I can elaborate on this.

Comment: ok thanks for the info

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Note that this is not true for every n. only for an n larger that n calculated based on k.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This is just for your curiosity (and for my fun).*

Assuming $n$ to be a real, consider the function $$f(n)=2^{n-k}-n-1$$ and its derivatives $$f'(n)=2^{n-k}\,\log (2) -1$$ $$f''(n)= 2^{n-k}\,\log ^2(2)$$ The first derivative cancels for $$n_*=k-\frac{\log (\log (2))}{\log (2)}\implies f(n_*)= 2^{n_*-k}\,\log (2)-n_*-1$$ So, the first derivative if negative for any $n \lt n_*$ and positive for any $n \gt n_*$. The second derivative being always positive, this point corresponds to a minimum. So, $f(n)=0$ has two roots.

By inspection, $$f(0)=2^{-k}-1 \qquad , \qquad f(-1)=2^{-k-1}$$ from which we can conclude that, as soon as $k \geq 1$, one root is such that $-1 \leq n_1\leq 0$. So for any $n < n_1$, $f(n) > 0$.

For sure, the second root will be $n_2 > n_*$ but the solution becomes much more complex. At a time, you will learn that any equation which can write or rewrite as $$A+B x+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has solutions which can be expressed in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). I shall not go through all details (you will find nice examples in the link) and for your case, the solution will be given by $$n_2=-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-2^{-k-1} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}-1$$ where appears the lower branch of Lambert function. Similarly $$n_1=-\frac{W\left(-2^{-k-1} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}-1$$

As you will see in the Wikipedia page, there are nice bounds $$-1-\sqrt{2u}-u < W_{-1}(-e^{-u-1}) < -1-\sqrt{2u}-\frac{2}{3}u$$ Replacing $$u=-\log \left(2^{-k-1} \log (2)\right)-1$$ will give you nice bounds for $n_2$.

For $k=20$, the above will give $21.45 < n_2 <28.14$ while the exact solution would be $n_2\approx 24.6827$.

Concerning approximations, you could notice that, for the first root, you could use $$n_1\approx x-x^2+\frac{3 x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and for the second root $$n_2\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1} \qquad L_1=\log (-x)\qquad L_2=\log(-L_1)$$ using $x=-2^{-k-1} \log (2)$. Applied to $k=20$, this would give $n_2\approx 24.6895$ which is quite good.

If $n$ is an integer and $k>1$, then the inequality holds for $n<-1$ and for $n>\lceil n_2\rceil$.